# How can I generate a random alpha-numeric string and have it plugged into a login/signup box for a group that is on the same (activity) page

Tags: java, android, authentication, parse-platform, alphanumeric

I want to have an activity that has a login button to make a random alpha-numeric string and when pressed populates a single login box on the same activity (page). This will be used for their user name/password. Then they just press the login button and it will create/signin a group named that string in Parse. Once the last person leaves the group I would like it torn down (deleted from parse.) That's is another problem though... I can get the random number generated and the login box created but connecting it all is my issue. (I am new to programming, like green as can bee maby a few weeks old.) Java for android.

Comment: Just define a long String array and use random to generate out of them  String[] alpha_numeric={'a','b','c','d','1','2','3'};String result="";Random rand=new Random(); for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ result+=alpha_numeric[rand.nextInt(alpha_numeric.length)];}

Comment: you can just have one button then correct and just hit login and it could genorate the random string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to generate unique ID's in Java.

1 minute google gave me out [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56).